# Check union of delimited strings for duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file called, for example, PM.INX, which is a comma-delimited listing of file details, with four fields per line. The files (there are about 12, with different filenames but the same structure) can contain 20-30 rows or several hundred rows. A couple of example lines would look like:

```
"2FLAT0.6","2FLAT0£6",2,33.82  
"BZ95M","BZ95M",1,36.26
```

- Field 1 is the actual name;
- Field 2 is the renamed file with any full-stops, ampersands or plus signs changed for a '£';
- Field 3 is sex code - 1 for Male, 2 for Female; and
- Field 4 is the checksum total of the items in the file.

When a user wants to add a new item, I need to check to see if that already exists, so need to split each line and check the new item doesn't already exist, compared against the first item.
So I could read the file into a string[], then loop through each item, split the data by row and check against my new item, but wondered if there was another (LINQ?) way to do this?

Comment: What benefit would LINQ offer over loops? What does your loop look like? You will need to read the entire file and parse all rows any way.

Comment: I only mentioned LINQ as I know it works fine if I'm only checking by the entire line  `fileContent.Intersect(newContent).Any()`  but wanted to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this (untested).

```
items
    .Select(x=>x.Split(',').Select(y=>y.Trim()).ElementAt(0))
    .Any(x=>x == newfilename);
```

Comment: Thanks @Niyoko. I'll have a play!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only one new item, the easiest and fastest method is to read each line and compare the key of the new item against the key all other items.

However, if you want to add many new items, this is very inefficient. It is a (roughly) O(n^2) operation. You can bring it down to a O(n) operation if you add the keys to a `HashSet<T>`. Accessing a hash set has a constant access time O(1).

Pseudo code

```
var keys = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (line in file) {
    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
    keys.Add(parts[0];
}

foreach (newKey in newKeys) {
    if (keys.Contains(newKey)) {
        // Item already exists
        ...
    } else {
        // New item
        keys.Add(newKey);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. It could be one or several new items, which was part of the reason I asked the question as wasn't keen on looping multiple times to check each file. Thanks. Martin